# Select a restricted subset of items based on child property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm just wondering if there's a better way to write this code, basically the source object contains a mix of items with a boolean property however the destination object has two lists which should contain the true/false items independently.

I've written it in Linq and it works just fine but it feels as though there's a better way. Any suggestions?

```
    void Main()
    {
        var s = new ResponseObject()
        {
            Results = new List<GroupedObject>()
                    {
                        new GroupedObject()
                        {
                            Name = "List A",
                            List=new List<DetailObject>()
                            {
                                new DetailObject{ Name = "Allowed", AllowedAccess = true},
                                new DetailObject{ Name = "Restricted", AllowedAccess = false}
                            }
                        },
                        new GroupedObject()
                        {
                            Name = "List B",
                            List=new List<DetailObject>()
                            {
                                new DetailObject{ Name = "Allowed", AllowedAccess = true},
                                new DetailObject{ Name = "Restricted", AllowedAccess = false}
                            }
                        }
                    }
        };

        var d = new ResponseViewModel();
        d.AllowedResults = FilterObjectsByAccess(s.Results, true);
        d.RestrictedResults = FilterObjectsByAccess(s.Results, false);

        // Other stuff
    }

    public IEnumerable<GroupedObject> FilterObjectsByAccess(IEnumerable<GroupedObject> source, bool allowAccess)
    {
        return source.Where(i => i.List.Any(c => c.AllowedAccess == allowAccess))
                     .Select(i => new GroupedObject()
                     {
                         Name = i.Name,
                         List = i.List.Where(c => c.AllowedAccess == allowAccess)
                     });
    }

    public class ResponseObject
    {
        public IEnumerable<GroupedObject> Results { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResponseViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<GroupedObject> AllowedResults { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GroupedObject> RestrictedResults { get; set; }
    }
    public class GroupedObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DetailObject> List { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool AllowedAccess { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One change that may be worth benchmarking would be changing:

```
public IEnumerable<GroupedObject> FilterObjectsByAccess(IEnumerable<GroupedObject> source, bool allowAccess)
{
    return source.Where(i => i.List.Any(c => c.AllowedAccess == allowAccess))
                 .Select(i => new GroupedObject()
                 {
                     Name = i.Name,
                     List = i.List.Where(c => c.AllowedAccess == allowAccess)
                 });
}
```

to:

```
public IEnumerable<GroupedObject> FilterObjectsByAccess(IEnumerable<GroupedObject> source, bool allowAccess)
{
    return source
                 .Select(i => new GroupedObject()
                 {
                     Name = i.Name,
                     List = i.List.Where(c => c.AllowedAccess == allowAccess).ToList()  // `ToList` here is optional - it is a trade-off between RAM and CPU
                 })
                 .Where(z => z.List.Any());
}
```

Your original code, with the use of `Any` then `Where` would enumerate `i.List` twice. The above change would likely improve that.

Another approach, which would likely involve even higher memory consumption could be to switch to using `ToLookup`:

```
        var d = new ResponseViewModel
        {
            AllowedResults =
                FilterObjectsByAccess(s.Results)
                    .Select(z => new GroupedObject() { Name = z.Name, List = z.GroupedList[false] })
                    .Where(z => z.List.Any()),
            RestrictedResults =
                FilterObjectsByAccess(s.Results)
                    .Select(z => new GroupedObject() { Name = z.Name, List = z.GroupedList[true] })
                    .Where(z => z.List.Any())
        };

        // Other stuff
    }

    public List<SpecialGroupedObject> FilterObjectsByAccess(IEnumerable<GroupedObject> source)
    {
        return source.Select(i => new SpecialGroupedObject()
        {
            Name = i.Name,
            GroupedList = i.List.ToLookup(c => c.AllowedAccess)
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Will give it a try and see what I get cheers. Good to see that there's not a massively obvious trick I was missing

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use `ToDictionary()` like this:

```
var result = new[] {true, false}.ToDictionary(k => k,
            v =>
                s.Results.Where(w => w.List.Any(x => x.AllowedAccess == v))
                    .Select(c => new GroupedObject {Name = c.Name, List = c.List.Where(l => l.AllowedAccess == v)}));

 var allowedResults = result[true];
 var restrictedResults = result[false];
```

Or this:

```
var result = s.Results
                .SelectMany(c => c.List, (b, c) => new {b.Name, DObj = c})
                .GroupBy(g => g.DObj.AllowedAccess)
                .ToDictionary(k=> k.Key,
                    c =>
                        new {
                            c.Key,
                            List =
                                c.GroupBy(cg => cg.Name)
                                    .Select(
                                        x => new GroupedObject {Name = x.Key, List = x.Select(l => l.DObj).ToList()})
                                    .ToList()
                        });
```